# Create a horizontal line 2px height - with 2 different colors

Tags: css, line, border

I want to create the effect of a single horizontal line that is 2 px high. Essentially two single pixel height lines sandwiched together. With each line being different colors.

So the first line (single pixel height) would blue. The second single pixel line directly underneath with no spacing, would be red.

Not sure if this can be achieved using `<HR>` or whether it would need to be a div with borders?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Haven't really found anything that works yet.

Comment: Is this just a visual effect or does it have some meaning? (i.e should it just be say a background or should it be an actual hr element splitting two sections for example?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this needs to be done at the bottom of a `div` without any additional DOM elements, you can achieve it using `box-shadow`. (However, the second line in red will not be occupying any space thus you might need to add a `margin-bottom` to compensate it)

Although it is named as `box-shadow`, when it is used without a `blur` / `spread` parameter, it looks exactly like a solid line / block.

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<hr>` is just a normal block element, which means we can style it using `border-*` properties:

```css
hr {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for visual effect don't add anything to the DOM, just draw a background image.

Here's an example:

```html
<style>
  div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, blue 0 1px, red 1px 2px, transparent 2px 100%);
  }
</style>
<div>some text in a div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create this by utilizing div element you can try this out,

```
<div style="height: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid blue; border-bottom-color: blue; border-bottom-style: solid;"></div>
<div style="height: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid red; border-bottom-color: red; border-bottom-style: solid;"></div>
```

The first one will have a blue border in the bottom, and the second div has a red border in the bottom. Also, if you try by setting the div height by 2px, then both borders will show as a continuous line.

Also, another way to tackle this and which i sometimes do is that you can use a  div element with a linear gradient background, here is a piece of my code:

```
<div style="height: 2px; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, red 50%);"></div>
```

This will merge 2 colors in the middle way, giving us the of a line with red and blue colors.